# Discord.js Bot giveaway command : embedSent.reactions.get is not a function

Tags: javascript, bots, discord

I am trying to make a Discord.js giveaway command that send an embed, save it to the variable embedSent then collect the reactions after the TimeOut with the `reactions.get()` method, but I keep getting the error `TypeError: embedSent.reactions.get is not a function` Here is the part of my code :

```
var embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
embed.setColor(0x3333ff);
embed.setTitle("Nouveau Giveaway !");
embed.setDescription("**" + item + "**");
embed.addField(`Durée : `, ms(ms(time), {
  long: true
}), true);
embed.setFooter("Réagissez à ce message avec  pour participer !");
var embedSent = await message.channel.send(embed);
embedSent.react("");

setTimeout(function () {
  var peopleReacted = embedSent.reactions.get("").users.filter(user => user.id !== client.user.id).array()
}, time);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after almost 2 months, I finally figured it out. The full, working command (DiscordJS v12) :

```
if (command == "giveaway") {
    // !giveaway {time s/m/d} {item}
    const messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
    if (!message.member.hasPermission(["ADMINISTRATOR"])) return message.channel.send("You don't have enough permissions to start a giveaway !")
    var item = "";
    var time;
    var winnerCount;
    for (var i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
      item += (args[i] + " ");
    }
    time = args[0];
    if (!time) {
      return message.channel.send(`Invalid duration provided`);
    }
    if (!item) {
      item = "No title"
    }
    var embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
    embed.setColor(0x3333ff);
    embed.setTitle("New Giveaway !");
    embed.setDescription("**" + item + "**");
    embed.addField(`Duration : `, ms(ms(time), {
      long: true
    }), true);
    embed.setFooter("React to this message with  to participate !");
    var embedSent = await message.channel.send(embed);
    embedSent.react("");

    setTimeout(async () => {
      try{
        const peopleReactedBot = await embedSent.reactions.cache.get("").users.fetch();
        var peopleReacted = peopleReactedBot.array().filter(u => u.id !== client.user.id);
      }catch(e){
        return message.channel.send(`An unknown error happened during the draw of the giveaway **${item}** : `+"`"+e+"`")
      }
      var winner;

      if (peopleReacted.length <= 0) {
        return message.channel.send(`Not enough participants to execute the draw of the giveaway **${item}** :(`);
      } else {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * peopleReacted.length);
        winner = peopleReacted[index];
      }
      if (!winner) {
        message.channel.send(`An unknown error happened during the draw of the giveaway **${item}**`);
      } else {
        console.log(`Giveaway ${item} won by ${winner.toString()}`)
        message.channel.send(` **${winner.toString()}** has won the giveaway **${item}** ! Congratulations ! `);
      }
    }, ms(time));
}
```

Hope it helped some !

Comment: Hi!
I need help with it,

Comment: So when i call the bot what should i enter !giveaway and in which  date/time?

Comment: @LZ The command syntax is : giveaway {time with [ms module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ms) syntax **without spaces**} {name of the giveaway}. Example : `!giveaway 3d Discord Nitro (1 month)` will start a 3 days giveaway called "Discord Nitro (1 month)".

Comment: Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1):

I guess this giveaway command works for me - Discord.js V13

- don't forget to have npm i ms installed if you haven't already

```js
const { Client, Intents, CommandInteraction, ReactionUserManager } = require('discord.js'); 
const INTENTS = new Intents(32767); // 32767 == full intents, calculated from intent calculator 

const client = new Client({
  intents: INTENTS
});

const Discord = require('discord.js');
const ms = require('ms') // make sure package ms is downloaded in console, to do this, simply type:   npm i ms     in your terminal
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/ms

client.once("ready" , () => {
    console.log("I am online!")
});

client.on('messageCreate', async message => {

    const prefix = "!" // this can be any prefix you want
    let args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ")

    // COMMAND FORMAT: !startgiveaway {duration} {winners} {#channel} {prize}
    // E.g. !startgiveaway 24h 3w #giveaways Free Discord Nitro

    if ((message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}startgiveaway`))) { // this condition can be changed to any command you'd like, e.g. `${prefix}gstart`
        if (message.member.roles.cache.some(role => (role.name === 'Giveaway') )) { // user must have a role named Giveaway to start giveaway
        let duration = args[1];
        let winnerCount = args[2];

        if (!duration) 
            return message.channel.send('Please provide a duration for the giveaway!\nThe abbreviations for units of time are: `d (days), h (hours), m (minutes), s (seconds)`');
        if (
            !args[1].endsWith("d") &&
            !args[1].endsWith("h") &&
            !args[1].endsWith("m") &&
            !args[1].endsWith("s") 
        )
            return message.channel.send('Please provide a duration for the giveaway!\nThe abbreviations for units of time are: `d (days), h (hours), m (minutes), s (seconds)`');

        if (!winnerCount) return message.channel.send('Please provide the number of winners for the giveaway! E.g. `1w`')

        if (isNaN(args[2].toString().slice(0, -1)) || !args[2].endsWith("w")) // if args[2]/winnerCount is not a number (even after removing end 'w') or args[2] does not end with 'w', condition returns:
            return message.channel.send('Please provide the number of winners for the giveaway! E.g. `3w`');
                if ((args[2].toString().slice(0, -1)) <= 0)   
                    return message.channel.send('The number of winners cannot be less than 1!');

            let giveawayChannel = message.mentions.channels.first();
            if (!giveawayChannel || !args[3]) return message.channel.send("Please provide a valid channel to start the giveaway!")

            let prize = args.slice(4).join(" ");
            if (!prize) return message.channel.send('Please provide a prize to start the giveaway!');

            let startGiveawayEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle(" GIVEAWAY ")
                .setDescription(`${prize}\n\nReact with  to participate in the giveaway!\nWinners: **${winnerCount.toString().slice(0, -1)}**\nTime Remaining: **${duration}**\nHosted By: **${message.author}**`)
                .setColor('#FFFFFF')
                .setTimestamp(Date.now() + ms(args[1])) // Displays time at which the giveaway will end
                .setFooter("Giveaway ends"); 

            let embedGiveawayHandle = await giveawayChannel.send({embeds: [startGiveawayEmbed]})
            embedGiveawayHandle.react("").catch(console.error); 

            setTimeout(() => {
                if (embedGiveawayHandle.reactions.cache.get("").count <= 1) {
                    return giveawayChannel.send("Nobody joined the giveaway :(")
                }
                if (embedGiveawayHandle.reactions.cache.get("").count <= winnerCount.toString().slice(0, -1)) { // this if-statement can be removed
                    return giveawayChannel.send("There's not enough people in the giveaway to satisfy the number of winners!")
                }

                let winner = embedGiveawayHandle.reactions.cache.get("").users.cache.filter((users) => !users.bot).random(winnerCount.toString().slice(0, -1)); 

                const endedEmbedGiveaway = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle(" GIVEAWAY ")
                .setDescription(`${prize}\n\nWinner(s): ${winner}\nHosted By: **${message.author}**\nWinners: **${winnerCount.toString().slice(0, -1)}**\nParticipants: **${embedGiveawayHandle.reactions.cache.get("").count - 1}**\nDuration: **${duration}**`)
                .setColor('#FFFFFF')
                .setTimestamp(Date.now() + ms(args[1])) // Displays time at which the giveaway ended
                .setFooter("Giveaway ended"); 

                embedGiveawayHandle.edit({embeds:[endedEmbedGiveaway]}); // edits original giveaway message to show that the giveaway ended successfully

                const congratsEmbedGiveaway = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setDescription(` Congratulations ${winner}! You just won **${prize}**!`)
                .setColor('#FFFFFF')

                giveawayChannel.send({embeds: [congratsEmbedGiveaway]}).catch(console.error); 
            }, ms(args[1]));

        } // end "Giveaway" role condition
    }
})

client.login('INSERT YOUR BOT TOKEN HERE');
```